# ¿Cómo se renderiza este extracto de código en Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, component

Tengo este trozo de código:

```
    <div id="counter-event-example">
    <p>{{ total }}</p>
    <button-counter v-on:increment="incrementTotal"></button-counter>
    <button-counter v-on:increment="incrementTotal"></button-counter>
    </div>

    Vue.component('button-counter', {
     template: '<button v-on:click="increment">{{ counter }}</button>',
     data: function () {
        return {
         counter: 0
        }
       },
      methods: {
       increment: function () {
       this.counter += 1
       this.$emit('increment')
        }
       },
      })

    new Vue({
    el: '#counter-event-example',
    data: {
     total: 0
    },
   methods: {
    incrementTotal: function () {
    this.total += 1
   }
  }
  })
```

¿Cómo se renderiza este trozo del código: `<button-counter v-on:increment="incrementTotal"></button-counter`?. ¿Será que `increment` se ejecuta primero que `ìncrementTotal`?.

Gracias por leer.

Comment: Hola Erick,bienvenido al sitio. a que te refieres exactamente con tu pregunta. _(Cómo se renderiza el código?)_  es claro que primero se ejecuta el evento `click` por lo tanto , primero será `increment`

Comment: @Dev.Joel gracias por tu respuesta. Realmente no me refería a cómo se renderiza, me refería **al porqué y de qué manera** se ejecuta el **orden** de los métodos en este trozo de código: `<button-counter v-on:increment="incrementTotal"></button-counter>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El componente padre es `counter-event-example` éste tiene como hijo a `button-counter`.

Pasarle datos del padre al hijo es trivial (usando props) pero pasarlos del hijo al padre no es tan trivial, y una de las soluciones es usar la emisión de eventos.

Cuando el componente hijo recibe un click, ejecuta el **metodo** `increment`

```
<button v-on:click="increment">{{ counter }}</button>
```

A su vez, el **método** `increment` emite el **evento** `increment`.

```
increment: function () {
  this.counter += 1
  this.$emit('increment')
}
```

Pasa que como se llaman igual, uno tiende a confundirse.

Ahora, cuando un componente hijo emite un evento ¿Quién lo recibe? El padre no lo recibe mágicamente, sino que explícitamente declara que cuando el hijo emita el **evento** `increment`, se ejecute en el padre el **método** `incrementTotal`

```
<button-counter v-on:increment="incrementTotal"></button-counter>
```

Entonces la cadena es:

```
- ButtonCounter.click <Evento>
  - ButtonCounter.increment <Método>
    - ButtonCounter.emit('increment' <Evento>)
      - CounterEventExample.incrementTotal <Método>
```

Comment: ¡Excelente amigo!. Ya entendí que es necesario `this.$emit('increment')` para que el padre sepa que se emitió el **evento** `ìncrement`, y así proceda a ejecutar a `incrementTotal`... Pero tengo una "espinita": ¿la sintaxis para que ocurra todo eso es necesario que sea así: `v-on:increment="incrementTotal"` ?

Comment: Claro, el `v-on` declara un listener sobre el hijo. Puedes probar metiendo más `button-counter` sin declarar el `v-on` y verás que aunque esos emiten, el padre no los escucha